# Bootstrap stay accordion open page reload

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

How can I make the accordion and sub accordion stay open if a reload the page (clicking one of the items)? Do I have to write an own function to save the items that are open on open them on the page reload or is that a possibility with the built in javascript of bootstrap.

```
<div id="MainMenu">
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#menu0" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Holz</a>
    <div id="menu0" class="collapse">
        <a href="/products/index/11" class="list-group-subitem">A</a>
        <a href="/products/index/12" class="list-group-subitem">B</a>
        <a href="/products/index/13" class="list-group-subitem">C</a>
        <a href="/products/index/14" class="list-group-subitem">D</a>
        <a href="#menu0_1" class="list-group-subitem" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">E</a>
        <div id="menu0_1" class="collapse">
            <a href="/products/index/15" class="list-group-subitem">E1</a>
            <a href="/products/index/16" class="list-group-subitem">E2</a>
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use the LocalStorage in javascript to store the open accordion id's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the LocalStorage or cookies. Here is one example with LocalStorage:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function() {
        //store the id of the collapsible element
        localStorage.setItem('collapseItem', $(this).attr('href'));
    });

    var collapseItem = localStorage.getItem('collapseItem'); 
    if (collapseItem) {
       $(collapseItem).collapse('show')
    }
})
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vcarvalho/4w6wx5w7/)

To improve the code you can use the bootstrap collapse events: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage, e.g.:

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  // store the id of the collapsible element
  //....
})
```

The same strategy could be used with cookies: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie